# StructureMap 2.0 samples / tutorials

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, structuremap

Does anyone know where can I find samples / tutorials covering one of these:

- Autowiring (is it supported?)
- StructureMap AOP support
- Configuration and such

I need these for StructureMap 2.0, which was the last version supporting .NET 2.0. The documentation that comes with the source is not really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my findings on these, that can also be found on the google's first page are:

http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/04/02/structuremap-2-0-is-released-inversion-of-control-and-dependency-injection-for-net-2-0/

http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/04/09/introduction-to-structuremap-2-0-part-1/

and the documentation tagged for 2.0

http://structuremap.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/structuremap/tags/Release_2.0/Docs/